# 動的に追加したscriptとクロスドメインについて

Tags: javascript

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://example.com/hoge.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

example.comは外部ドメインとします。
この場合クロスドメイン制約になりますでしょうか？

また制約にひっかかる場合、スクリプトのダウンロードはブラウザでされますか？

すぐに試せる環境がないのと、そのあたりのフローが曖昧だったので、
ご教授願いたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

scriptタグを使った場合、CORSの `Access-Control-***` ヘッダがなくとも、別オリジンからスクリプトを読み込んで実行することができます。

実際、CORSが普及する前にクロスオリジンの通信を行う方法として使われていたJSONPは、サーバーから送りたいデータをJavascriptコードの形にしてscriptタグで読み込ませることで、クロスオリジンでのデータの受け渡しを可能にしていました。

ただしCORSが全く無関係というわけではなく、別オリジンのスクリプトで発生したエラーを `window.onerror` で読み取る際に制限があります。これを回避したい場合は `Access-Control-***` ヘッダが必要になるようです。

- [同一オリジンポリシー - Web セキュリティ | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
- [how to fix the cryptic "Script error." in javascript ? | ravikiranj.net](http://ravikiranj.net/posts/2014/code/how-fix-cryptic-script-error-javascript/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ぜひご教授いただきたいのですが、
質問にある別ドメインと想定したhoge.js
内で、さらにscriptタグを生成し、外部のドメインのjsをsrcに指定し、DOMに追加した場合、
こちらも別オリジンからの読み込み実行が可能なのでしょうか？
動的に追加したscriptから、さらにscriptを動的に生成し、別のオリジンのスクリプトを実行する流れです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @hata はい、可能です。具体例として、アクセス解析などをまとめて読み込む、Googleタグマネージャなどのサービスがあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
疑問点解消しました。解決させて頂きます。